# "Stackoverflow has been compromised" post

Tags: discussion, security

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963613) (10k+ only) claims that StackOverflow DB have been compromised with a link for a [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/thehackernews/photos/a.197666140247267.65555.172819872731894/1239824726031398/?type=3) picture and a download link to a torrent file. This may be nothing but I prefer to ask the question to be sure.

[image]

What should we do? Is this personal data or just stats about the site? Does the users that logs without OpenID should change their passwords?

Comment: Entirely possible that it's just a hoax. The linked FB posts claims that the torrent is "*9GB zip file (70GB in total)*", but Stack Exchange/Overflow's database is actually 1.3 TB in size, uncompressed.

Comment: @Cupcake But isn't that just the posts, and not users?

Comment: Then let's just break the hoax! (@Cupcake thanks for the picture btw)

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/

Comment: Those tags on the deleted question - epic; I guess [tag:php] [tag:android] [tag:c++] [tag:ios]  can be seen as "attempt to reach a wide audience". But [tag:objective-c], really :)

Comment: But almost everything here are all public anyways, what to hack? Downloading people's email addresses and sell them to the spammers?

Comment: @chmod711telkitty some password?

Comment: Passwords are not encrypted? ~gasp~

Comment: @chmod711telkitty I hope they are!

Comment: @chmod711telkitty and Thomas: No they're not. Encrypting passwords is a bad idea, because you could decrypt them. They're hashed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189823/how-does-se-store-passwords-for-their-open-id-provider/189833#189833

Comment: @balpha *and* salted, right?  Salted hash is the best hash.

Comment: @Will Yes, the post I linked to has a link to the source code. We follow industry standard best practices (tm). Your security is very important (tm) to us ;)

Comment: @Will Some people like their hash salted *and* peppered. Too much trouble, I say. Pass the Tabasco, I'm hungry.

Comment: I was going to make a salt and hash joke, but @ThisSuitIsBlackNot beat me to it `:P`.

Comment: This is a hoax.

Comment: For those that do not click the meta-link @balpha shared – single-round salted hash is inadequate for password storage. One should use a key derivation function like scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 (which you will see if you click the link in balpha's comment), which employ a hash for multiple rounds.

Comment: @balpha – just hoping to clarify for anyone reading (but not clicking your link).  Someone reading through the comments might conclude that e.g. sha512 is adequate, and there is no mention in the comments of any KDF (which should be part of any conversation on password storage).  I've re-posted my comment with a little extra. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Complete nonsense. That's the torrent of our [regular public data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Note the torrent URL, the "hacker" is database guru extraordinaire Brent Ozar, and it's linked on http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/.

If you refresh https://stackoverflow.com/error often enough, you can even see evidence of Brent conducting his hack:

[image: error page photo of Brent Ozar]

Comment: Well that Facebook post nowhere claims that this is the result of a hack, and the OP (of the Facebook post) even clarifies in the comments "Released by admins... no personal info included.". So you've mostly trolled yourself :)

Comment: ok  but to be fair, Brent's picture in that blog post does look like he's just successfully hacked something and going "muahahahaha".

Comment: @Pekka웃 looks like he hacked his mouse into a phone.

Comment: Now you're going to have a whole backlog of 500's to look at

Comment: @topher give me $100 and I'll make you one!

Comment: There, you've done it. I just spent 10 minutes cycling through every picture on the error page, just to make absolutely sure I didn't miss one. Are you happy now?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page

Comment: @balpha Well there goes my excuse. Back to [compiling](https://xkcd.com/303/), I guess.

Comment: Brent here. Yeah, no hacking involved, just plain ol' importing and sharing.

Comment: @BrentOzar That's what a hacker would say...

Comment: This reminds me when a few years ago someone uploaded a torrent "Hacker tool: complete list of all IP addresses". This was, of course, just a generated list of the ~4 billion IPv4 addresses, but thousands of "h4xx0rz" downloaded it. Look mum, imahacker!

Comment: The unending ignorance on that FB comment thread is almost amusing.

Comment: Brent looks hella shady in the picture above!